# How to update custom report template

Tags: civireport, custom-reports

I am using 4.7.13 on two different sites. On one site, when I update the class and refresh my custom report, all of the changes are visible. On the other site when I do the same thing, the changes are not visible. Even stranger, when I delete the class (i.e., the PHP file), the report is still visible in its old form. I have tried 'flush all cache' and searching for any other cached versions without success. Since this works on one site but not the other I suspect there is some configuration setting that I am missing somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may have an override file in place.  Check **Administer » System Settings » Directories** to get the custom PHP path, then look in the appropriate subfolder (if it exists) for an override file.

Comment: The override file is where I have placed my new class which is based on the Sybunt class, but it has a different classname and filename. This directory is the only place this class should exist.

Comment: I am still having difficulties with this. Once a class has been registered, it never gets updated. My only recourse is to change the class name and filename by appending a suffix. I should not have to do this.

Comment: Issue was traced to opcache, which was running on one site, but not the other. Followed the instructions here (https://ma.ttias.be/how-to-clear-php-opcache/) to clear the cache and that resolved the problem.

Comment: @RDooman Thank you for reporting back!  Feel free to post that as a separate answer here and mark it "accepted".  It will help others and get you some upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was traced to opcache, which was running on one site, but not the other. Followed the instructions here (ma.ttias.be/how-to-clear-php-opcache) to clear the cache and that resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One word - ***pseudoconstants***. Put clear_cache=1 in a call in the CiviAPI and see what happens.

Comment: Maybe my mention of flushing the cache was misleading. Since my new code is not being invoked at all, I'm not sure how adding a call would do anything. I can tell it is not being invoked because I add a field in the __construct() function, and that field does not appear in the 'Columns' tab of the report. I am modifying the out-of-the-box CRM_Report_Form_Contribute_Sybunt class, which as far as I can tell doesn't have any CiviAPI calls anyway.

Comment: Same applies. Give it a go in an API call outside that class, i.e. with the API explorer.

Comment: This had no impact. Executed the following from API explorer: $result = civicrm_api3('Contribution', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'clear_cache' => 1,
));